# Function to show table rows

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make function show or hide table rows with a dropdown list. There is no response from function when selecting element from dropdown. Classes work fine when hiding/displaying in CSS manually. The if statement doesn't have an else to simplify code.

```
<select id="vendorselect" onselect="tableshow()">
  <option>Select vendor:</option>
  <option id="Capintec">Capintec</option>
  <option id="Exradin">Exradin</option>

</select>

<table class="ionchambers">
  <tr class="CapintecTbl">
    <td>Capintec PR-05P mini</td>    
    <td>1.046</td><td>1.045</td><td> 1.044</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ExradinTbl">
    <td>Exradin P425</td>  
    <td>1.046</td><td>1.045</td><td>1.044</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
function tableshow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("vendorselect").value;
  if (table == "Capintec") {                         
    document.getElementsByClassName("CapintecTbl").style.display='inline-block';
    document.getElementsByClassName("ExradinTbl").style.display='none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onselect` for `onchange`.

```
<select id="vendorselect" onchange="tableshow()">
  <option>Select vendor:</option>
  <option id="Capintec">Capintec</option>
  <option id="Exradin">Exradin</option>
</select>
```

Also, the JavaScript selectors are not working.
Try changing them for these:

```
document.querySelector(".CapintecTbl").style.display='inline-block';
document.querySelector(".ExradinTbl").style.display='none';
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the querySelector. Interesting how it's not referenced as an option in many places.